# How to sum values and Consolidate duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I have a table which looks like show below in the picture but i want to sum the `AMOUNT REMAINING` and merge duplicates, if `SHIPPED COMPLETE NOT EQUAL COMPLETE`  or `AMOUNT REMAINING  NOT EQUAL to 0` .

[image]

I want to see the new table as

```
 Part Number      Quantity Used In WO 
 400443               8
 400571               8
 400458               8
 400441               28 // 14+14
 400497               28 // 14+14
 200391               28 // 14+14
 201937               28 // 14+14
 201804               6
 201283               9
 400629               1
```

i tried the following code but i cant sum and merge duplicates and insert distinct record into Mysql table

```
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "
 INSERT INTO demand (PartNo,qty) VALUES (?, ?)");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $itemid, $qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$recordd = $tv->search(56554000270957, 's=2'); 
 foreach($recordd as $data2) { 
    $itemrim = $data2['fields']['RIM PN (MRP)']; 
   $itemtire = $data2['fields']['TIREPN']; 
    $qty = $data2['fields']['QUANTITY'];

        if ($data2['fields']['AMOUNT REMAINING)']!=0 || $data2['fields']['SHIPPED COMPLETE)'] !="COMPLETE") {


         //Sum (value of $data2['fields']['QUANTITY'];) of duplicate item


        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));

}
```

//print_r

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 99994000270957
            [table_id] => 56554000270957
            [created] => 2014-09-08T18:53:03-0600
            [updated] => 2016-04-26T12:37:12-0600
            [created_by] => 3000045174
            [updated_by] => 3000045538
            [fields] => Array
                ([MRP Wheel] => 500356
                 [TIRE PN] => 200248
                 [RIM PN (MRP)] => 400479
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to fetch records use sql `sum()` to add amount

```
select RIMPN(MRP),TIREPN, sum(AMOUNT_REMAINING) as QUANTITY from table_name group by RIMPN(MRP)
```

Another way with creating new array..

```
<?php 
$recordd = array(0=>array('id'=>99994000270957,'fields'=>array('RIM PN (MRP)'=>'400441','TIREPN'=>200391,'QUANTITY'=>14)),
                 1=>array('id'=>99994000270958,'fields'=>array('RIM PN (MRP)'=>'400441','TIREPN'=>200391,'QUANTITY'=>14)),
                 2=>array('id'=>99994000270959,'fields'=>array('RIM PN (MRP)'=>'400497','TIREPN'=>201937,'QUANTITY'=>14))
                 );

$newArray = array();
foreach($recordd as $data2)
{ 
  $newArray[$data2['fields']['RIM PN (MRP)']][] = $data2;
}   

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO demand (PartNo,qty) VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $itemid, $qty) or die(mysqli_error($con));

foreach($newArray as $key => $val)
{ 
    $itemid = $val[0]['fields']['RIM PN (MRP)'];
    $qty = array_sum(array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['fields']['QUANTITY'];}, $val));
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}   

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am using `INSERT` Statement it seems like it working i used this statement `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = qty + $qty"); `

Comment: I'm asking about first time, when you fetch all the records from first table to update into new table, then you can use this query to get unique records and insert directly into new table, then there is no need to use `qty = qty + $qty`

Comment: I use API to fetch record from the first table here `$recordd = $tv->search(56554000270957, 's=2'); `

Comment: now what is the problem or error you are getting ??

Comment: i think its working for me now this  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty = qty + $qty")` give me the solution Thanks  @Manjeet Barnala

Comment: @Kin There is one another way also, check my answer I've added code

Comment: but how can i implement insert statement and `$recordd` contains more than 20 fields or  whole row `$recordd = $tv->search(56554000270957, 's=2'); ` . here is how i feacth fiekd `$rim = $data2['fields']['RIM PN (MRP)']`my insert statement doesn't work right it keep adding or  sum `qty = qty + $qty"` work once but ..next time it just added to the value

Comment: @Kin, please check the answer and so something like this

Comment: it works for the given array but how can i change the array `$recordd = $tv->search(56554000270957, 's=2'); ` this is the array

Comment: can you show me the format of your array .. just `echo "<pre>"; print_r($recordd);` and show me..

Comment: added at the end of my question. Thanks!